# Jquery radio button check causing form to work incorrectly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a radio form questionnaire that should when the user submits their results take them to a specific page. However since adding the code to make sure that all the radio buttons have to be checked before the user can submit the code acts incorrectly, always taking the user to one specific page (the last in the below if statement (software.html).

This is the code for the html questionnaire

```
 <form id="quiz">
    <!-- Question 1 -->
    <h2>Do you enjoy fixing things</h2>
    <!-- Here are the choices for the first question. Each input tag must have the same name. For this question, the name is q1. -->
    <!-- The value is which answer the choice corresponds to. -->

      <div class="questionsWrap">
    <label><input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1" value="c1">
      Yes
    </label><br />
    <label><input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1" value="c2">
      No
    </label><br />
    <label><input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1" value="c3">
      Maybe
    </label><br />
      </div>

<div class="questionsWrap">
    <!-- Question 2 -->
    <h2>Do you enjoy problem solving?</h2>
    <!-- Here are the choices for the second question. Notice how each input tag has the same name (q2), but a different name than the previous question. -->
    <label><input type="radio" name="q2" value="c2">
      Yes
    </label><br />
    <label><input type="radio" name="q2" value="c1">
      No
    </label><br />
    <label><input type="radio" name="q2" value="c3">
      Unsure
    </label><br />
      </div>

    <div class="questions">
    <!-- Question 3 -->
    <h2>Do you enjoy maths?</h2>
    <!-- Choices for the third question -->
    <label><input type="radio" name="q3" value="c2">
      Yes
    </label><br />
    <label><input type="radio" name="q3" value="c1">
      No
    </label><br />
    <label><input type="radio" name="q3" value="c3">
      Unsure
    </label><br />
      </div>

    <div class="questions">
    <!-- Question 4 -->
    <h2>Do you often take thing apart to rebuild them?</h2>
    <!-- Choices for the fourth question -->
    <label><input type="radio" name="q4" value="c1">
     Yes
    </label><br />
    <label><input type="radio" name="q4" value="c2">
     No
    </label><br />
    <label><input type="radio" name="q4" value="c3">
      I have never done it before so i don't know
    </label><br />
      </div>

    <div class="questions">
      <!--Question 5 -->
      <h2>Hardware or Software?</h2>
      <label><input type="radio" name="q5" value="c1">
          Hardware</label><br />
       <label><input type="radio" name="q5" value="c2">
         Software</label><br />
      </div>

    <button type='button' id="submit" onclick="answers()">Submit Your Answers</button>

      <button type="reset" id="reset" onclick="resetAnswer()">Reset</button>

  </form>
```

This is the code that calculates the questionnaire result

```
<script>

function answers(){
  // initialize variables for each choice's score
  // If you add more choices and outcomes, you must add another variable here.
  var c1score = 0;
  var c2score = 0;
  var c3score = 0;


  // get a list of the radio inputs on the page
  var choices = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
  // loop through all the radio inputs
  for (i=0; i<choices.length; i++) {
    // if the radio is checked..
    if (choices[i].checked) {
      // add 1 to that choice's score
      if (choices[i].value == 'c1') {
        c1score = c1score + 1;
      }
      if (choices[i].value == 'c2') {
        c2score = c2score + 1;
      }
      if (choices[i].value == 'c3') {
        c3score = c3score + 1;
      }


      // If you add more choices and outcomes, you must add another if statement below.
    }
  }

  // Find out which choice got the highest score.
  // If you add more choices and outcomes, you must add the variable here.
  var maxscore = Math.max(c1score,c2score,c3score);

  // Display answer corresponding to that choice
  var answerbox = document.getElementById('answer');


  if (c1score == maxscore) { // If user chooses the first choice the most, this outcome will be displayed.

      window.location.href='Hardware.html';

  }
 if (c2score == maxscore) { // If user chooses the second choice the most, this outcome will be displayed.
      window.location.href='Software.html';

  }

 /* if (c3score == maxscore) { // If user chooses the third choice the most, this outcome will be displayed.
       alert("no third career sector page currently exists in this version");
      window.location.href='questionnaire1.html';
  }
  */

  // If you add more choices, you must add another response below.
}
    </script>
```

This is the code that causes the issue, it should stop the user from submitting the form if not all the radio buttons have been submitted.

```
      <script>
  $(function(){
    $('button[type=button]').click(function(){

        var all_answered = true;
        $(':radio').each(function(){
            if($(':radio[name='+$(this).attr('name')+']:checked').length == 0)
            {
                all_answered = false;
            }
        });
        alert(all_answered);
    }); 
});

    </script>
```

Comment: Uh, you can't check all radios.  By their very nature, they are exclusive of other radios with the same name

Comment: could i wrap them up in a div and then perform the check?

Comment: You need to logically make sure that for each radio button name, one of those radios is checked.  So you could select the radios, get an array of their unique names, and then do that check.

Comment: thankyou for the reply. I'm just wondering if i could possible use the HTML required attribute instead and set it to each group of radio buttons?

Comment: i've updated my code, it works to check if the groups are selected but it still takes the user to a page.

Comment: You're not preventingDefault anymore.

Comment: I've added e.preventDefault(); to my method but it does not work at all now